# What is returned in .then() for Table.bulkPut in Dexie?

Tags: dexie

I'm using Dexie for my webapp. However from the documentation I couldn't get what bulkPut exactly return on success.

For example:
Let's say in my DB I have three objects with the id's 1, 3 and 5. For the example I'll just show it as an array of ints: DB = [**1**, **3**, **5**].

My application has asked the server to give me all items from the server. I received an array with four objects: *result* = [2, 3, 4, 5].
2 and 4 are new items, 3 is the same as 3 in my DB, but has been modified. 5 is not modified and therefore equal to my DB object.

I expect the following output from bulkAdd and bulkPut:

When I use Table.bulkAdd(*result*, {allKeys: true}) where I catch the errors, I expect the following outcome:
My DB contains: [**1**, 2, **3**, 4, **5**] and my .then() will return a promise, containing the id's of 2 and 4.

When I use Table.bulkPut(*result*, {allKeys: true}) where I catch the errors, I expect the following outcome:
My DB contains: [**1**, 2, 3, 4, **5**] and my .then() will return a promise, containing the id's 2, 3 and 4. Because 5 was not modified and therefore hasn't been replaced.

I expect the promises of the methods only to return the keys of the values that actually have been added/modified. Is this assumption correct? Because in practise this is not what happens in my application.
In my application I use bulkPut (so that I can add and update my data with one method), but somehow it always returns 2 keys of items, regardless of the input being an array containing modified items or existing items.

Answer (score 0):

bulkPut() with option {allKeys: true} returns an array with the same length as given input array. All keys are returned regardless of whether the put operation would result in new, updated or identical data. If exception occurs and you catch it, you will only have the error object.

Comment: I was missing the allKeys option in use case and received an array with 2 keys. That got me confused, but now I get it. I am using a compound PK, so the bulkPut returned an array with both keys. Thank you!